# Read from pivot table and write in to a new page

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to create a pivot table using Apache POI. My program reads from an Excel file and creates the pivot using the input data. But while writing the pivot to a new sheet the output obtained is along with input that was provided.
How can I separate the pivot and the data received? This is the code i am using now.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\aaa\\Dump.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
XSSFSheet data = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("PIVOT SHEET");
System.out.println(data.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
System.out.println(data.getRow(0).getLastCellNum());
CellReference cr = new CellReference("A1");
CellReference c1 = new CellReference(0, 0);
CellReference c2 = new CellReference(data.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - 1,       data.getRow(0).getLastCellNum() - 1);
AreaReference ar = new AreaReference(c1, c2);
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(ar, cr, data);
pivotTable.addRowLabel(7);
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 6);
```

FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new   File("D:\aaa\out.xlsx")); 
   workbook.write(output_file); 
     fis.close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //data sheet
    XSSFSheet data = wb.getSheet("DATA SHEET");
    // sheet you want pivot table in
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("PIVOT SHEET");

    CellReference cr = new CellReference("A1");
    CellReference c1 = new CellReference(0, 0);
    CellReference c2 = new CellReference(data.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - 1, data.getRow(0).getLastCellNum() - 1);
    //source data
    AreaReference ar = new AreaReference(c1, c2);
    XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(ar, cr, data);
    //add row labels and other stuff to pivot table
    pivotTable.addRowLabel(10);
    pivotTable.addRowLabel(11);
    pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
    pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 0);
```

i hope this is what you are looking for. please tell me if i understood your question wrong

for adding another column use:

```
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(4).setAxis(STAxis.AXIS_COL);
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(4).addNewItems();
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(4).getItems().addNewItem()
        .setT(STItemType.DEFAULT);
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields().addNewField().setX(4);
```

you have to do it for every column you want to add

Comment: you got it right. Thanks for the replay. But why u r passing 3 parameters to the createPivotTable, I am not clear with that. And why you are using 3 row labels there? If i am filtering based on one column, we need to add only one row label i think.

Comment: i just used that method cause the "description" looked more helpful. i didn't try the method without source sheet, therefore i don't know if/how it works. you didn' t point out how many labels you need. for my task i had to add 3

Comment: if you need to add another column label refer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398493/apache-poi-how-to-apply-workbook-style-to-all-pivot-tables-how-do-i-exclude-she . the 4 lines after create pivot table add another column label

Comment: okey thanks my friend. I when i am trying this i am getting a new sheet in the  same workbook, but when i am trying to open it it is showing an error that the pivot feature has been removed because of some issue.

Comment: what exactly is the error? i had some kind of that error too. can you provide some more code?

Comment: Thanks i fixed it. Its working fine now. But is there any way that we can add few more columns to the pivot.

Comment: posted it in answer