# Apache Poi set data field style for pivot table

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to set the style for 2 sheets in 1 workbook, but I have a total of 6 sheets. I can set the style for all with

```
wb.createDataFormat().putFormat((short) 0, "_($* #,##0.00_);_($*(#,##0.00);_($* \"-\"??_);_(@_)");
```

,but this is not what I want, since its applying the style to a sheet which doesn't represent data about money. Does anyone has an idea on how to set the style only for specific sheets?
PS: the style should apply to pivot tables

Comment: If you don't get a response here, you should search through the Apache POI user and dev mailing lists and bugzilla. I think XSSFPivotTable still requires modifying the CT* classes. If you create a workbook with a pivot table, save it, then style a column in the pivot table, and save it, then unzip both workbooks and diff the XML, you'll be halfway to a patch.

Comment: @IceArdor where can i find the xml's? I am not used to work with xml and such. can you maybe clarify it a bit more what you mean?

Comment: Xlsx files are actually zip files. Rename the extension to zip and extract the zip archive. Inside you will find xml files.

Comment: ahh okay nice to know, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i actually found a solution on setting the format of the data area.

[How to set PivotTable Field Number Format Cell with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511928/how-to-set-pivottable-field-number-format-cell-with-apache-poi)

on this link the answer is posted. simply use the `setFormatDataField` method to set the style. you can also define your own format as example like this `short accounting = wb.createDataFormat().getFormat("_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* \"-\"??_);_(@_)");` and set it with a call like this `setFormatDataField(pivotTable, 2, accounting);`. I hope this helps some more people who are searching for an answer